# Найти индекс уникального элемента массива

Tags: javascript

Есть массив из трех целых элементов, один из элементов отличается от других, остальные одинаковы, нужно сравнить элементы, и вывести индекс элемента отличного от остальных. Пробовал через reduce, но безуспешно. Как это можно сделать?

```
const arr = [3, 3, 5];
```

Comment: "Пробовал через reduce" - ??

Comment: Если массив всегда именно из трех элементов, то подумайте, как это можно сделать просто с тремя переменными, две из которых одинаковы, а третья отличается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно, например, так:

```js
const arr = [3, 3, 5];

const index = arr.findIndex(el => arr.indexOf(el) === arr.lastIndexOf(el));

console.log(index);
```